# Difference between 'sudo gem install something' and 'gem install something'

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, sudo, mac

In this case I'm using `gem` as an example, but I think it can be extended to any other program.

I use a Mac and I installed `rails` using command `gem install rails` from  directory `/Users/myusername/workstation`. Then I tried to run `rails new somename` and this is the output:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails
```

I would expect being able to execute commands from the program I just installed from my 'domain' (username directory). Obviously it doesn't work like that, at least in this case. What am I missing? What is the proper way of installing and dealing with programs you are going to user frequently?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be on topic here. You may be able to get help at one of our sister sites, such as [apple.se] or [unix.se].